# Коробки - задача на if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
c1 = int(input())
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())
c2 = int(input())

# сортировка по величине первых трех сторон
if a1 >= b1 and b1 >= c1:
    s1 = a1
    s2 = b1
    s3 = c1
elif a1 >= b1 and c1 >= a1:
    s1 = c1
    s2 = a1
    s3 = b1
elif a1 >= c1 and c1 >= b1:
    s1 = a1
    s2 = c1
    s3 = b1
elif b1 >= a1 and b1 >= c1:
    s1 = b1
    s2 = a1
    s3 = c1
elif b1 >= c1 and c1 > a1:
    s1 = b1
    s2 = c1
    s3 = a1
elif c1 > a1 and b1 > a1:
    s1 = c1
    s2 = b1
    s3 = a1

# сортировка по величине вторых трех сторон
if a2 >= b2 and b2 >= c2:
    w1 = a2
    w2 = b2
    w3 = c2
elif a2 >= b2 and c2 > a2:
    w1 = c2
    w2 = a2
    w3 = b2
elif a2 >= c2 and c2 > b2:
    w1 = a2
    w2 = c2
    w3 = b2
elif b2 > a2 and a2 >= c2:
    w1 = b2
    w2 = a2
    w3 = c2
elif b2 >= c2 and c2 > a2:
    w1 = b2
    w2 = c2
    w3 = a2
elif c2 > a2 and b2 > a2:
    w1 = c2
    w2 = b2
    w3 = a2
if s1 == w1 and s2 == w2 and s3 == w3:
    print("Boxes are equal")
elif s1 >= w1 and s2 >= w2 and s3 >= w3:
    print("The first box is larger than the second one")
elif w1 > s1 and w2 > s2 and w3 > s3:
    print("The first box is smaller than the second one")
else:
    print("Boxes are incomparable")
```

> Есть две коробки, первая размером A₁×B₁×C₁, вторая размером A₂×B₂×C₂. Определите, можно ли разместить одну из этих коробок внутри другой, при условии, что поворачивать коробки можно только на 90 градусов вокруг ребер.

Формат ввода

Программа получает на вход числа A₁,B₁,C₁,A₂,B₂,C₂.

Формат вывода

Программа должна вывести одну из следующих строчек:

Boxes are equal, если коробки одинаковые,

The first box is smaller than the second one, если первая коробка может быть положена во вторую,

The first box is larger than the second one, если вторая коробка может быть положена в первую,

Boxes are incomparable, во всех остальных случаях.

Решение только с помощью if. Помогите найти ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Повороты позволяют поменять A, B, C местами, чтобы [отсортировать 3 стороны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739079/23044) и получить `A <= B <= C`. Это позволяет легко определить находится ли одна коробка в другой:

```
def sorted3(a, b, c):
    if c < b: c, b = b, c  # swap
    if c < a: c, a = a, c
    if b < a: b, a = a, b
    return a, b, c

input_box = lambda: sorted3(*[int(input()) for _ in range(3)])
a, b = input_box(), input_box()
if a == b:
    print('equal')
elif all(x <= y for x, y in zip(a, b)):
    print('a inside b')
elif all(x <= y for x, y in zip(b, a)):
    print('b inside a')
else:
    print('incompatible')
```

Здесь `all(x <= y for x, y in zip(a, b))` равнозначно: `A1 <= A2` и `B1 <= B2` и  `C1 <= C2`.

#### [Пример](https://ideone.com/Yx5Lkc)

```
2
1
3
1
2
2
```

#### Результат

```
b inside a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
x, y, z = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if a > c:
    a, c = c, a
if b > c:
    b, c = c, b
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
if x > z:
    x, z = z, x
if y > z:
    y, z = z, y
if x > y:
    x, y = y, x
if a == x and b == y and c == z:
    print('Boxes are equal')
elif a <= x and b <= y and c <= z:
    print('The first box is smaller than the second one')
elif a >= x and b >= y and c >= z:
    print('The first box is larger than the second one')
else:
    print('Boxes are incomparable')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif w1 >= s1 and w2 >= s2 and w3 >= s3:
print("The first box is smaller than the second one")
```

Попробуй так исправить третье условие.

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
c1 = int(input())
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())
c2 = int(input())
if a1 == c2 and b1 == b2 and c1 == a2 or a1 == c2 and b1 == a2 and c1 == b2:
    print('Boxes are equal')
elif a1 == a2 and b1 == b2 and c1 == c2 or a1 == a2 and b1 == c2 and c1 == b2:
    print("Boxes are equal")
elif a1 == b2 and b1 == c2 and c1 == a2 or a1 == b2 and b1 == a2 and c1 == c2:
    print("Boxes are equal")
elif a1 >= a2 and b1 >= b2 and c1 >= c2 \
        or a1 >= a2 and b1 >= c2 and c1 >= b2 \
        or a1 >= b2 and b1 >= a2 and c1 >= c2 \
        or a1 >= b2 and b1 >= c2 and c1 >= a2:
    print("The first box is larger than the second one")
elif a1 >= c2 and b1 >= b2 and c1 >= a2 or a1 >= c2 and b1 >= a2 and c1 >= b2:
    print("The first box is larger than the second one")
elif a1 <= a2 and b1 <= b2 and c1 <= c2 \
        or a1 <= a2 and b1 <= c2 and c1 <= b2 \
        or a1 <= b2 and b1 <= a2 and c1 <= c2 \
        or a1 <= b2 and b1 <= c2 and c1 <= a2:
    print("The first box is smaller than the second one")
elif a1 <= c2 and b1 <= b2 and c1 <= a2 or a1 <= c2 and b1 <= a2 and c1 <= b2:
    print("The first box is smaller than the second one")
else:
    print('Boxes are incomparable')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1 = int(input())  # Box 1
B1 = int(input())
C1 = int(input())
A2 = int(input())  # Box 2
B2 = int(input())
C2 = int(input())
if ((A1 == A2 and B1 == B2 and C1 == C2) or
        (A1 == A2 and B1 == C2 and C1 == B2) or
        (A1 == C2 and B1 == A2 and C1 == B2) or
        (A1 == B2 and B1 == A2 and C1 == C2) or
        (A1 == B2 and B1 == C2 and C1 == A2) or
        (A1 == C2 and B1 == B2 and C1 == A2)):
    print('Boxes are equal')
elif ((A1 <= A2 and B1 <= B2 and C1 <= C2) or
        (A1 <= A2 and B1 <= C2 and C1 <= B2) or
        (A1 <= C2 and B1 <= A2 and C1 <= B2) or
        (A1 <= B2 and B1 <= A2 and C1 <= C2) or
        (A1 <= B2 and B1 <= C2 and C1 <= A2) or
        (A1 <= C2 and B1 <= B2 and C1 <= A2)):
    print('The first box is smaller than the second one')
elif ((A1 >= A2 and B1 >= B2 and C1 >= C2) or
        (A1 >= A2 and B1 >= C2 and C1 >= B2) or
        (A1 >= C2 and B1 >= A2 and C1 >= B2) or
        (A1 >= B2 and B1 >= A2 and C1 >= C2) or
        (A1 >= B2 and B1 >= C2 and C1 >= A2) or
        (A1 >= C2 and B1 >= B2 and C1 >= A2)):
    print('The first box is larger than the second one')
else:
    print('Boxes are incomparable')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Parametres of BOX 1
a1 = int(input())
b1 = int(input())
c1 = int(input())
#Parametres of BOX 2
a2 = int(input())
b2 = int(input())
c2 = int(input())
#Sorting parametres of BOX 1 from MAX to MIN
if b1 > a1:
    a1, b1 = b1, a1
if b1 < c1:
    c1, b1 = b1, c1
if a1 < b1:
    a1, b1 = b1, a1
#Sorting parametres of BOX 2 from MAX to MIN
if b2 > a2:
    a2, b2 = b2, a2
if b2 < c2:
    c2, b2 = b2, c2
if a2 < b2:
    a2, b2 = b2, a2
#Checking if MAX sides MID sides and MIN sides are aqual (so boxes are equal)
if a1 == a2 and b1 == b2 and c1 == c2:
    print('Boxes are equal')
#Checking if BOX 1 is bigger
elif a1 >= a2 and b1 >= b2 and c1 >= c2:
    print('The first box is larger than the second one')
#Checking if BOX 2 is smaller
elif a1 <= a2 and b1 <= b2 and c1 <= c2:
    print('The first box is smaller than the second one')
else:
    print('Boxes are incomparable')
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучшее решение)!

```
A = sorted(list(map(int, input().split( ))))
B = sorted(list(map(int, input().split( ))))
a = A[0] * A[1] * A[2]
b = B[0] * B[1] * B[2]

if a == b and A[0] == B[0] and A[2] == B[2]:
  print("Boxes are equal")
elif a >= b and A[2] >= B[2] and A[1] >= B[1] and A[0] >= B[0]:
  print('The first box is larger than the second one')
elif a <= b and A[2] <= B[2] and A[1] <= B[1] and A[0] <= B[0]:
  print('The first box is smaller than the second one')
else:
  print('Boxes are incomparable')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]